# Do I need to visitor pattern in my design

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

I am working on designing html parser for study purpose. Where I am first creating a overall design.

Data structure to store html element.

`Base` : HtmlBaseElement

`Derived` : HTMLElement, PElement, HtagElemement, ImgElement, BodyElement, StrongElement

Basically I will create derived class for each type of element in html.

I need to write this html file back to a file and allow user to add element in already parsed html file.

This is what I am thinking :

First Approach:

1. Create a `BaseVisitor` which is having visit function for each type of element.
2. Create a Derived Visitor Class `WriteHtmlVisitor` to write whole file which will `visit` each element in HTML datastructure.

Second Approach:

I can also use a class `WriteHtmlFile` , having object of `HTMLElement` and then write this using getter of all elements.

Which is best way to write html file and adding new elements in file.

I am just looking for suggestion, as this is in design phase.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually four patterns here:

1. Base class having all important fields to print (your second approach)
2. virtual fn call and pass base class ptr
3. Dynamic visitor pattern, as you wrote
4. Static visitor pattern

   1. will induce moderate antipathy amongst sw architects, whereas in practice it might just work fine and is very quick. The issue here will be that you'll always have a new derived class with new derived schematics that require new data (or different porcessing of existing data), thus your base class will be ever-changing and very soon you'll reimplement dynamic dispatch using switch statements. On the pro side, it's the fastest and, if you get the base data structs right, it'll work for long time. A rule of thumb is, if you can (not necessarily will) pass all inputs of print() from derived ctor to base ctor, you're ok. Here it works, as you just fill attributes and content (I suppose).
   2. Is slow and is only good as long as you have a very few methods that are very close-coupled with the class. It might work here to add a pure virtual print() to base and implement in derived classes; however, ehen you write the 147th virtual, your code becomes a spaghetti.
      Another issue with virtuals that it's an open type hierarchy, which might lead to clients of your lib implementing descendants. Once they start doing that, you'll have much less flexibility in cangeing your design.
   3. Is just what you wrote. It's a bit slower than virtual, but still acceptable in most situations. It's a barrier for many junior coders to understand what's behind the scenes. Also, you're bound to a specific signature (which is not a problem here); otherwise it's easy to add new implementations and you won't introduce new dependencies to the base class. This works if you have many print-like actions (visitors). If you have just this one, perhaps it's a bit complex for the task, but remember that where there's one, there'll be more. It's a closed hierarchy with visitors being 'subscribed' (compile-time error) if a new descendant is added, which is sometimes useful.
   4. is basically 3 w/o virtuals, so it's quick. You either pass variant or sometimes just the concrete class. All the design considerations listed in (3) apply to this one, except that it's even more difficult to make juniors / intermed. coders understand it (template anxiety) and that it's extremely quick compared to (2) - (4).

At the end of the day, it boils down to:

- do you want an open or closed hierarchy
- junior/senior ratio and corp. culture (or amongst readers)
- how quick it must be
- how many actions / signatures do you envision

There's no single answer (one size does not fit all), but thinking about the above questions help you decide.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend following:

**- Visitor pattern -** In this context, though you can apply it, the basic purpose of this pattern is to take out operations as part of this pattern, which is not the case here. You are only concerned about write operation (with varying implementation) but here it does not seem to be the case of dynamic operations.

**- Strategy pattern -** you can leverage strategy pattern instead and initially, you can start with `SimpleDiskStorageStrategy` and as you design evolve, you can have multiple strategies in future such as `CachingStorageStrategy` or `DatabaseStorageStrategy`.

**- Composite pattern -** As your requirement is traversal and dynamic handling of elements in structure (adding/removing elements), I think it is a structural problem than behavioral. Hence, try to use Composite & Builder pattern (if complexity increases).

**- Flyweight pattern -** Use it for creating and maintaining the reference of all html objects (you can pass State object for each HTML document type). This will help better memory management when parsing many html documents and effectively better storage on disk.